# Jmeter Dashboard Report: How to show each thread group in report

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a JMeter test plan with multiple thread groups. When I execute my test plan and generate a dashboard report, it shows all the sampler with their statistics. I want to segregate the report to show results for each thread group separately in the same report.

Example: A thread group : steps of thread group : Statistics

Answer (score 6):

1. You can use [__threadGroupName() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadGroupName) as a prefix for your Samplers

   [image]

   it will result in the following dashboard report:

   [image]
2. If you don't want individual samplers but cumulative summary of all samplers in the Thread Group - put all the Samplers under [Transaction Controllers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller),tick `Generate parent sampler` box and set `jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults` property to `false`

   [image]

   it will result in the following report:

   [image]

Comment: Great! I just utilized the first solution and now I can see sampler results thread vice. 

Thanks.

Comment: I tried but it doesnt give the me the cumulative results. If the sampler names are changed then it mentions that as well in the HTML report and

Comment: @azeembhopal Hi I tried but the html report doesnt print the cumulative result if I change the sample name.